# Error:class domdocument not forund in debian server

Tags: laravel, debian

In debian am getting an error as

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError
>   (E_ERROR)
>
> Class 'DOMDocument' not found

I run these command

```
sudo apt-get install php-dom
sudo apt-get install php7.3-xml
sudo service apache2 restart
```

when I want to forget password mail am still getting the above error.

Comment: Are you using php fpm ?